# Azure Local Git deployment - multiple credentials

Tags: git, azure, deployment

I have two App Services and deployment is set with Local Git. I reset deployment credentials for the Proj1 to 'user1', Proj2 for 'user2'. If I go now and do `git push azure master` for Proj1 it asks for login/pass and succeeds when provided. But then I go to Proj2 and do the same - `git push azure master` (the remote is different and it includes user2). And it doesn't ask for login/pass for the first time. ok, I run the same command again - it asks this time. I type correct creds but get auth fatal error every single time! The only way to fix it is to go to the Portal and reset deployment credentials.

So, every time I deploy those 2 projects I need to go to the portal and reset the creds. Is there anything else I can do to make it just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portal is very confusing, but you have only one set of *deployment credentials* and it is tied to your Azure login, as explained in [this documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials):

> **User-level credentials (aka Deployment Credentials)**
>
> These are the credentials that you choose yourself in the Azure
>   portal. If you're not sure what they are, you can reset them by going
>   to the Dashboard tab for any site and clicking 'Reset deployment
>   credentials' (under quick glance).
>
> These credentials are directly tied to a Microsoft Account, and not to
>   a particular web app. This needs to be emphasized, because the Azure
>   portal UI is a bit confusing, as you need to go under a specific site
>   on order to change them. But changing them under one site affects all
>   of them!

So you can't have project or website-level crendentials.
What you are doing is changing back and forth your only credentials, therefore you have to type it every singe time. When you think you're reseting credentials for Project 2, you're also reseting Project 1.